# cURL POST array of images

Tags: ruby, curl, ruby-grape

How do we POST an array of images using cURL?

I am using Grape API.

```
    requires :foo, type: Array do
      optional :bar, type: String
      optional :baz, type: Rack::Multipart::UploadedFile
    end
```

I want to test this using cURL.
Request:

```
    curl -X POST -F "foo[][bar]=bar&foo[][baz]=@image.png"\
        'http://localhost:5000/image_upload'
```

The above request results in:

```
    [{"bar":"bar\u0026foo[][baz]=@image.png"}]
```

The resulting format should be:

```
   [
      {bar: "bar1", baz: image_to_be_uploaded1},
      {bar: "bar2", baz: image_to_be_uploaded2}
   ]
```

Where as this POSTs image correctly. How do I send both the params in a single request?

```
      curl -X POST -F "foo[][baz]=@image.png"\
       'http://localhost:5000/image_upload'
```

Answer (score 0):

We have to specify the -F option (HTTP multipart POST data) twice

```
     curl -X POST -F "foo[][bar]=bar" -F "foo[][baz]=@image.png"\
          'http://localhost:5000/image_upload'
```